# Internet Explorer browser issue while click shift + mouse-left-click , the text automatically get highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have render html table with multiple select option. while I was clicked shift + mouse-left-click , td element text automatically gets highlighted in ie( Internet Explorer) browser only(chrome, firefox, safari are working fine ). 
Can you please help me how to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: add your code js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

use below code working fine.

```
document.onselectstart = function() { return false; }
document.onmousedown = function() { return false; }
```

Thanks